# Notify thread when data is added in queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

I have one thread which is adding data in the queue, now I want that other thread should get notified when the data is added so that it can start processing data from queue.

one option is thread will poll the queue continuously to see if count is more than zero but I think this is not good way, any other suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Any suggestion how I can achieve this, I am using .net framework 3.5.

and what if i have two thread one is doing  `q.Enqueue(data)` and other is doing `q.dequeue()`, in this case do i need to manage the lock..?

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Producer-Consumer-inter-aeaa9578 or use `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent`

Comment: Yes, you need a lock for the queue. But the second thread doesn't know when something is added to the queue. You don't want to poll (queue.peek), you could use events to trigger the second thread, you still need locking the queue. Look at my example, this is working with events (no polling), and locks the queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ManualResetEvent` to notify a thread.

```
ManualResetEvent e = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

After each `q.enqueue();` do `e.Set()` and in the processing thread, you wait for items with `e.WaitOne()`.

If you do processing inside a loop, you should do `e.Reset()` right after `e.WaitOne()`.

Comment: I advise instead using the ManualResetEvent to use the **AutoResetEvent**. The ManualResetEvent.Reset() can go wrong when something is queued between the WaitOne() and the Reset()

Answer (score 1):

I don't use queue's, because I'd rather batch process them. This is more usefull when you have to open/close (log)files, open/close databases. Here is an example how I create such:

```
// J. van Langen
public abstract class QueueHandler<T> : IDisposable
{
    // some events to trigger.
    ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ManualResetEvent _terminated = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    AutoResetEvent _needProcessing = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    // my 'queue'
    private List<T> _queue = new List<T>();

    public QueueHandler()
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            // what handles it should wait on.
            WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { _terminating, _needProcessing };

            // while not terminating, loop (0 timeout)
            while (!_terminating.WaitOne(0))
            {
                // wait on the _terminating and the _needprocessing handle.
                WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);

                // my temporay array to store the current items.
                T[] itemsCopy;

                // lock the queue
                lock (_queue)
                {
                    // create a 'copy'
                    itemsCopy = _queue.ToArray();

                    // clear the queue.
                    _queue.Clear();
                }

                if (itemsCopy.Length > 0)
                    HandleItems(itemsCopy);
            }

            // the thread is done.
            _terminated.Set();

        })).Start();
    }

    public abstract void HandleItems(T[] items);

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        // lock the queue to add the item.
        lock (_queue)
            _queue.Add(item);

        _needProcessing.Set();
    }

    // batch
    public void Enqueue(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        // lock the queue to add multiple items.
        lock (_queue)
            _queue.AddRange(items);

        _needProcessing.Set();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // let the thread know it should stop.
        _terminating.Set();

        // wait until the thread is stopped.
        _terminated.WaitOne();
    }

}
```

For the `_terminating`/`_terminated` I use a `ManualResetEvent` because those are only set ones.

For the `_needProcessing` I use an `AutoResetEvent` It can't be done with a ManualResetEvent, because when it's triggered, another thread could `Set` it again, so if you `Reset` it after the WaitHandle.WaitAny you could undone newly added items. (hmmm, if anyone could explain this easier, be welcome. :)

Example:

```
public class QueueItem
{
}

public class MyQueue : QueueHandler<QueueItem>
{
    public override void HandleItems(QueueItem[] items)
    {
        // do your thing.
    }
}


public void Test()
{
    MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();

    QueueItem item = new QueueItem();
    queue.Enqueue(item);

    QueueItem[] batch = new QueueItem[]
    {
        new QueueItem(),
        new QueueItem()
    };

    queue.Enqueue(batch);

    // even on dispose, all queued items will be processed in order to stop the QueueHandler.
    queue.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: thanks for such thorough explanation at present ManualResetEvent will be okay for me as from  your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BlockingCollection` class. This nice thing about it is that the `Take` method blocks (without polling) if the queue is empty. It is included in .NET 4.0+ or as part of the [Reactive Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) download or maybe even the [TPL backport via NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/). If you want you can use the following unoptimized variation of the class.

```
public class BlockingCollection<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> m_Queue = new Queue<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (m_Queue)
        {
            m_Queue.Enqueue(item);
            Monitor.Pulse(m_Queue);
        }
    }

    public T Take()
    {
        lock (m_Queue)
        {
            while (m_Queue.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(m_Queue);
            }
            return m_Queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public bool TryTake(out T item)
    {
        item = default(T);
        lock (m_Queue)
        {
            if (m_Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                item = m_Queue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        return item != null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think BlockingCollection would do better then Queue. Other then that, continuously checking queue size (and pausing the thread when its zero) is quite ok approach.

Btw, we are talking producer-consumer pattern here. I guess you can google it for some other approaches.

Comment: ouch, was pretty sure BC is older 8(